# "sudo pecl install mongodb" not working on macOS

Tags: php, mongodb, php-extension, pecl, php-mongodb

I am trying to install MongoDB PHP extension on macOS Catalina v10.15.7 by running the following command,

`sudo pecl install mongodb`

But it is throwing below error at the end,

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.13_1/pecl/20190902/mongodb.so'

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 294

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.13_1/share/php@7.4/pear/System.php on line 294
ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.13_1/pecl/20190902
```

PHP location is — `/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin/php`

PECL location is — `/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin/pecl`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Applied below solution and it worked,

`pecl config-get ext_dir | pbcopy`

`mkdir -p {paste clipboard value}`

`sudo pecl install mongodb`

Answer (score 0):

If that fails, try this

```
CFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/include pecl install mongodb
```